# How to read and write with mmap() on a Linux system

Tags: linux, mmap, segment

I need to make some stream in and out classes using mmap() in Linux. To do so I tried to make some test code that writes some integers to a file, saves it, loads it again and write the data in the file to cout. If that test code works, then It wont be a problem making stream in and out afterwards.

When I first started out I got segment faults and If I did not get that nothing happened, so I googled a little. I found this book http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch05-ipc.pdf where around page 107 there is some usefull code. I copy pasted that code and made some small changes and got this code:

```
int fd;
void* file_memory;

/* Prepare a file large enough to hold an unsigned integer.  */
fd = open ("mapTester", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

//Make the file big enough
lseek (fd, 4 * 10 + 1, SEEK_SET);
write (fd, "", 1);
lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

/* Create the memory mapping.  */
file_memory = mmap (0, 4 * 10, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
close (fd);

/* Write a random integer to memory-mapped area.  */
sprintf((char*) file_memory, "%d\n", 22);

/* Release the memory (unnecessary because the program exits).  */
munmap (file_memory, 4 * 10);

cout << "Mark" << endl;

//Start the part where I read from the file

int integer;

/* Open the file.  */
fd = open (argv[1], O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

/* Create the memory mapping.  */
file_memory = mmap (0, 4 * 10, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
close (fd);

/* Read the integer, print it out, and double it.  */
scanf ((char *) file_memory, "%d", &integer);
printf ("value: %d\n", integer);
sprintf ((char*) file_memory, "%d\n", 2 * integer);

/* Release the memory (unnecessary because the program exits).  */
munmap (file_memory, 4 * 10);
```

But I get a segment fults after the "mark" cout.

Then I replace the "read part" with this:

```
fd = open("mapTester", O_RDONLY);

int* buffer = (int*) malloc (4*10);

read(fd, buffer, 4 * 10);

for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    cout << buffer[i] << endl;
}
```

That is some working code that shows me that the file is empty. I tries out a couple of ways to write to the mapping without any change in result.

So how am I amble to make my code write? 
And does my mmap read code seem okay (just in case you can see some obvious flaws)?

I have found some other resources that did not help me yet, but because I am a new user I may only post max 2 links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test the result of [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap). If it gives `MAP_FAILED` check out [errno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) to find out why.

And you'll better mmap a multiple of pages, often 4K bytes each, and given by [sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf)

You can use [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to find out the size of (and many other numbers about) some given file.

You could use `strace` on existing Linux programs to learn what syscalls they are doing.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266365/841108) about `/proc/` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I found out that the file i wrote to where write protected and because of that everything failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf()` call should be `sscanf()`, and the second open should use `"mapTester"` instead of `argv[1]` as the filename.  When I fix these bugs, your posted program works (printing out `22` and leaving `44` in the file).

Comment: I could not get the code working with the changes you said. I dont know how to format code in a comment so I just put it at the end of the message. I use the g++ compiler command, maybe you are using another one?

Comment: Okay I cant add more code, because it is to long. I copied the code i wrote in here and changed the 2 places and it came with a segmentation fault in the last part of the code. But thanks for the 2 good sugestion, very helpful :)